# Chrome iframe's location.href is undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe

I'm working over the same domain giving the ability for a user to navigate within the iframe on the page. I'd like to handle the onload of the iframe in Chrome and to process the actual href the user navigated to. When I'm trying to access

```
document.getElementById("contentFrame").contentWindow.location.href
```

it says `undefined`. Debugger tells that `location` is an object, but I cannot figure out what property to use.

any guess?
Chrome v15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really are on the same domain, use the same protocol and port it should work. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/csVcL/1/

Maybe you're on different subdomains, in which case you need to use [document.domain](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/doc_domain.html)

Comment: excellent catch. My ports were different and this was not a cross-domain issue in IE. Eventually Chrome appeared to think different

Answer (score 0):

If you are not in the same domain, you are not allowed to access the href or any other properties on the remote window.

Comment: I've especially emphasized that the domain is the same